# Under what conditions on the sets $A$ and $B$ will it be true that $A\times B= B\times A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Under what conditions on the sets $A$ and $B$ will it be true that $A\times B= B\times A$?

I think it should be set $A$ $=$ set $B$
but don't know how to prove it
or is there any other way for those two cross product to be true?

Comment: In addition to the situation you described (where $A=B$), $A\times B=B\times A$ will be true if one of $A$ and $B$ is empty, regardless of what the other one is.

Answer (score 2):

Iff $A = B$ or $A = \varnothing$ or $B = \varnothing$. Indeed, if $A \neq \varnothing$ and $B \neq \varnothing$, fix $b \in B$. Let $a \in A$. We have $(a,b) \in A \times B$, so $(a,b)\in B \times A$, $\therefore a \in B$. $\therefore A \subset B$. Now fix $a \in A$ and do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

To prove the only possibilities are $A=B$ or one is empty, assume $A$ and $B$ are non-empty and distinct.  WOLOG there is an element $a \in A$ such that $a \not \in B$ and an element $b \in B$.  Then $(a,b)\in A \times B$ but $(a,b) \not \in B \times A$